# How can I view and post to a Facebook Group page in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

There is lots of stuff about posting on Facebook from iOS, but it seems to be rather blindly posting.

I want to be able to **view** the posts on a group page through, say, a UITableView. I don't want the user to be able to leave this page unless they touched a user, in which the Facebook app would open up and the user would go view that person. I would simply have a UIWebView that shows the group page, but I don't want the notification center and all that stuff there too. I want this so be very plain and simple. A keyboard comes up and you can post text, photo, or video directly to the group Facebook page.

I can't seem to find anywhere that talks about viewing posts on a wall...

Comment: I dont think you want to use a UIWebView because then you cant customize that UI. You'll want to use the fb API to access that fb groups posts, etc., and just load them into a UITableView yourself.